# Convert from strtotime into date

Tags: php

Im trying to convert the timestamp into a date:

```
echo '<td>' . strtotime(mysql_result($result,$i,"datum_overboeking")) = date('d-m-Y'). '</td>';
```

This gives me an error: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

I want the strtotime output do an input in the date ('d-m-y') so it will output the given date format.

update:

Perfect it works, thanks !

But how can you find this way of correct syntax construction because Im always struggling how to correctly build up a syntax like this ?

Comment: What do you expect `strtotime(mysql_result($result,$i,"datum_overboeking")) = date('d-m-Y')` to do?  You probably want to pass the timestamp to `date()` as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: Whatever you're intending, that `= date()`  assignment is suspect.

Comment: I want the strtotime output do an input in the date ('d-m-y') so it will output the given date format.

Answer (score 2):

Use the second parameter of the date function.

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime(mysql_result($result,$i,"datum_overboeking")));
```

look at the date function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: How can you find this way of correct syntax construction because Im always struggling how to correctly build up a syntax like this.

Comment: I added the link to the php net date function, I'm not sure what you are asking, could you specify

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it to work but Im still struggling with the understanding how to build up any given syntax and how to correctly build up the syntax string. Im always using examples from the internet that I then adjust.

Comment: basically you can build the string any way that you want using the given constants of the date function.

Comment: Well that was the point because it didnt worked for me:

strtotime(mysql_result($result,$i,"datum_overboeking")) = date('d-m-Y') - V.S -

date('d-m-Y', strtotime(mysql_result($result,$i,"datum_overboeking")));

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
     <?php
    $overboeking = mysql_result($result,$i,"datum_overboeking");

    try {
        $date = new DateTime($overboeking);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit(1);
    }

    echo '<td>'.$date->format('d-m-Y').'</td>';
    ?>
```